# Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision не работает

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть персонаж с лейером (Player) и платформа с лейером( Platform) и Platfrom effector на ней же. Хочу чтоб при нажатие на S персонаж мог проходить сквозь эту платформу вниз. Нашел метод Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision, но что-то не работает
вот код

```
void FixedUpdate () {

    playerLeyer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("player");
    platformLeyer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("platform");
    InputHoriz = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    isonPlatform = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(platformcheck.position, checkradios, whatis);
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(InputHoriz* speed, rb.velocity.y);
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up*m_JumpForce;
    }
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)&& isonPlatform == true)
    {     
            Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(playerLeyer, platformLeyer,true);  
    }
}
```

}

В чем загвоздка может.
В начале скрипта просто объявление переменных

Comment: Все.Вопрос решен.

Comment: Оформите ваше решение, как ответ, не стоит оставлять вопрос без ответа.